# Error al imprimir XML creado en Java

Tags: java, xml, xstream

Buen día, estoy desarrollando un programa que mediante clases me logre generar un XML, este es mi código, el cual NO tiene ningún error, no me marcar error en ninguna línea.
(Estoy desarrollando con las librerías xstream)

#### Libro

```
package ejemplo.xstream;
public class Libro {
    private String tipo;
    private String titulo;
    private String autor;
    public Libro(String tipo, String titulo, String autor) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.autor = autor;
    }
    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }
    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }
    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }
    public String getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }
    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

}
```

#### Biblioteca

```
package ejemplo.xstream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Biblioteca {
    List<Libro> libros=new ArrayList<Libro>();
    public Biblioteca(Libro libro) {
        this.libros.add(libro);
    }
    public List<Libro> getLibros() {
        return libros;
    }
    public void add(Libro libro) {
        this.libros.add(libro);
    }
}
```

#### StringConverter

```
package ejemplo.xstream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.SingleValueConverter;
public class StringConverter implements SingleValueConverter {
    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class arg0) {
        return arg0.equals(String.class);
    }
    @Override
    public Object fromString(String arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(Object arg0) {
        return (String) arg0;
    }

}
```

#### XstreamTransformacion

```
package ejemplo.xstream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;
public class XstreamTransformacion {
    private static XStream configuracion(){
        XStream xstream=new XStream(new DomDriver());
        xstream.alias("biblioteca", Biblioteca.class);
        xstream.alias("libro", Libro.class);
        xstream.addImplicitCollection(Biblioteca.class, "libros");
        xstream.useAttributeFor(Libro.class, "tipo");
        xstream.registerConverter(new StringConverter());   
        return xstream;
    }
    public static String toXML(Biblioteca biblioteca){
        XStream xstream=XstreamTransformacion.configuracion();
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"+xstream.toXML(biblioteca);
    }             
    public static Biblioteca fromXML(String xml){
        XStream xstream=XstreamTransformacion.configuracion();
        return (Biblioteca)xstream.fromXML(xml);
    }
}
```

#### Pruebas

```
package ejemplo.xstream;
public class Pruebas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Biblioteca biblioteca=new Biblioteca(new Libro("Novela", "Don quijote", "Miguel de cervantes"));
        biblioteca.add(new Libro("teatro", "Romeo y julieta", "William Shakespeare"));
        biblioteca.add(new Libro("cuento", "El Aleph", "Jorge Luis Borges"));
        biblioteca.add(new Libro("poemas", "Antologia", "Mario Benedetti"));
        String xml=XstreamTransformacion.toXML(biblioteca);
        System.out.println(xml);
    }

}
```

Y me arroja todos estos errores:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.InitializationException: Could not
>   instantiate mapper : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.LambdaMapper     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.buildMapperDynamically(XStream.java:646)
>     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.buildMapper(XStream.java:623)   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:587)     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:515)     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:484)     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:430)     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:397)     at
>   ejemplo.xstream.XstreamTransformacion.configuracion(XstreamTransformacion.java:6)
>     at
>   ejemplo.xstream.XstreamTransformacion.toXML(XstreamTransformacion.java:15)
>     at ejemplo.xstream.Pruebas.main(Pruebas.java:9) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.LambdaMapper  at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.CompositeClassLoader.loadClass(CompositeClassLoader.java:148)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.buildMapperDynamically(XStream.java:642)
>     ... 9 more

A que se deberá? 
gracias!

Comment: Igual sería de ayuda si incluyes otros detalles, como la manera en que estás agregando al class path tu jar de xtream (ant, maven, gradle, bazel, ivy, etc) y tu versión de Java (1.4,1.5,1.6,.7,8,9,10,11)

Answer (score 1):

El error es sólo uno, lo que ves es el *stack trace* de la ejecución en el momento del fallo:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   **com.thoughtworks.xstream.InitializationException**:  **Could not instantiate mapper : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.LambdaMapper** at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.buildMapperDynamically(XStream.java:646)
>   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.buildMapper(XStream.java:623) at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:587) at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:515) at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:484) at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:430) at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:397) at
>   ejemplo.xstream.XstreamTransformacion.configuracion(XstreamTransformacion.java:6)
>   at
>   ejemplo.xstream.XstreamTransformacion.toXML(XstreamTransformacion.java:15)
>   at ejemplo.xstream.Pruebas.main(Pruebas.java:9) **Caused by**:
>   java.lang.**ClassNotFoundException**:
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.**LambdaMapper** at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.CompositeClassLoader.loadClass(CompositeClassLoader.java:148)
>   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.buildMapperDynamically(XStream.java:642)
>   ... 9 more

Fíjate en las negritas. No encuentra en tiempo de ejecución una clase la librería *xstream*. Asegúrate de que el classpath es el correcto y apunta al jar de dicha librería.

Comment: Entonces solo me faltaría por aplicar esa liberia...

Answer (score 1):

yo segui estos pasos y con tu codigo funciono correctamente.

- Descargue la libreria XStream (http://x-stream.github.io/download.html)
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Apunte a los jar descomprimidos de la libreria
- Cargue tus clases

Esta es la salida por consola de la clase Prueba.

[image: Salida en consola de la clase Prueba]

Saludos.

Comment: Si pudieras incluir que versión de xstream usaste sería más útil tu pregunta

Comment: Listo, editada.